# Multiple values from input to different SQL rows

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this option select:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="assignee" name="assignee" style="max-width: 300px;">
    <option value="Employee1 | employee1@email.com">Employee 1</option>
    <option value="Employee2 | employee2@email.com">Employee 2</option>
    <option value="Employee3 | employee3@email.com">Employee 3</option>
 </select>
```

And I want to use the explode/_POST feature to separate the two:

```
 <?php
        $result = $_POST['assignee'];
        $result_explode = explode('|', $result);
        echo "Employee: ". $result_explode[0]."<br />";
        echo "EmployeeEmail: ". $result_explode[1]."<br />";
 ?>
```

Which I know will give me both options, but I was wondering how I could post those into different SQL rows for later use? Is the answer in the `$_POST` part of the PHP?

Comment: Why not have an employee table that has the employee ID and an email address?  Then you can just do a lookup to get that information or store the foreign key relation.

Comment: iterate over `$result_explode` array (for-loop). if you've difficulties, let me know, so i can provide more help.

Comment: You could assign the values to an array, like this: `$empArray = array($result_explode[0] => $result_explode[1]);` and then use this array to post to different SQL rows.

Comment: @kyle I think that would be a perfect solution but I currently don't have access to the SQL so I have to work with the fields I have.